# Is there a way to have interactive modal dismissal for a .fullscreen modally presented view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog

I want to enable interactive modal dismissal that pans along with a users finger on a fullscreen modally presented view controller `.fullscreen`.
I've seen that it's fairly trivial to do so on the `.pageSheet` and the `.formSheet` which have it built in but have not seen a clear example for the full screen.
I'm guessing I'd need to have a pan gesture added to my vc within the body of it's code and then adjust for the states myself but wondering if anyone knows what exactly needs to be done / if there's a simpler way to do it as it seems much more complicated for the `.fullscreen` case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with creating your custom `UIPresentationController` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`. Lets say we have `TestViewController` and we want to present `SecondViewController` with total `presentedHeight` of 1.0 (fullScreen). Presentation will be triggered with `@IBAction func buttonPressed` and can be dismissed by dragging controller down (as we are used to it). It would be also nice to add some `backgroundEffect` to be gradually changed while user is sliding down the `SecondViewController` (especially when used only `presentedHeight` of 0.6).

1. Firstly we define `OverlayViewController`  which will be later superclass of presented `SecondViewController`and will contain `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

   ```
      class OverlayViewController: UIViewController {

      var hasSetPointOrigin = false
      var pointOrigin: CGPoint?
      var delegate: OverlayViewDelegate?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerAction))
       view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

      }

      override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       if !hasSetPointOrigin {
        hasSetPointOrigin = true
        pointOrigin = self.view.frame.origin
       }
      }
      @objc func panGestureRecognizerAction(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

    // Not allowing the user to drag the view upward
    guard translation.y >= 0 else { return }
    let currentPosition = translation.y
    let originPos = self.pointOrigin
    delegate?.userDragged(draggedPercentage: translation.y/originPos!.y)

    // setting x as 0 because we don't want users to move the frame side ways!! Only want straight up or down
    view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.pointOrigin!.y + translation.y)

    if sender.state == .ended {
        let dragVelocity = sender.velocity(in: view)
        if dragVelocity.y >= 1100 {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Set back to original position of the view controller
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view.frame.origin = self.pointOrigin ?? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 400)
                self.delegate?.animateBlurBack(seconds: 0.3)
            }
        }
      }
     }
    }

    protocol OverlayViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func userDragged(draggedPercentage: CGFloat)
    func animateBlurBack(seconds: TimeInterval)
    }
   ```
2. Next we define custom `PresentationController`

   ```
      class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {

        private var backgroundEffectView: UIView?
        private var backgroundEffect: BackgroundEffect?
    private var viewHeight: CGFloat?
    private let maxDim:CGFloat = 0.6
    private var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    convenience init(presentedViewController: UIViewController,
                     presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?,
                     backgroundEffect: BackgroundEffect = .blur,
                     viewHeight: CGFloat = 0.6)
    {

        self.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)

        self.backgroundEffect = backgroundEffect
        self.backgroundEffectView = returnCorrectEffectView(backgroundEffect)
        self.tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
        self.backgroundEffectView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.backgroundEffectView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.backgroundEffectView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.viewHeight = viewHeight
    }

    private override init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?) {
        super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
    }

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.containerView!.frame.height * (1-viewHeight!)),
               size: CGSize(width: self.containerView!.frame.width, height: self.containerView!.frame.height *
                                viewHeight!))
    }

    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 0
        self.containerView?.addSubview(backgroundEffectView!)
        self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
            switch self.backgroundEffect! {
            case .blur:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 1
            case .dim:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = self.maxDim
            case .none:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 0
            }
        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in })
    }

    override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
        self.presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
            self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
            self.backgroundEffectView?.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }

    override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    override func containerViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.containerViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
        backgroundEffectView?.frame = containerView!.bounds
    }

    @objc func dismissController(){
        self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func graduallyChangeOpacity(withPercentage: CGFloat) {
        self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = withPercentage
    }

    func returnCorrectEffectView(_ effect: BackgroundEffect) -> UIView {
        switch effect {

        case .blur:
            var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
            }
            return UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        case .dim:
            var dimView = UIView()
            dimView.backgroundColor = .black
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                dimView.backgroundColor = .gray
            }
            dimView.alpha = maxDim
            return dimView
        case .none:
            let clearView = UIView()
            clearView.backgroundColor = .clear
            return clearView
        }
       }
      }

        extension PresentationController: OverlayViewDelegate {
        func userDragged(draggedPercentage: CGFloat) {
        graduallyChangeOpacity(withPercentage: 1-draggedPercentage)

        switch self.backgroundEffect! {
        case .blur:
            graduallyChangeOpacity(withPercentage: 1-draggedPercentage)
        case .dim:
            graduallyChangeOpacity(withPercentage: maxDim-draggedPercentage)
        case .none:
            self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    func animateBlurBack(seconds: TimeInterval) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: seconds) {
            switch self.backgroundEffect! {
            case .blur:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 1
            case .dim:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = self.maxDim
            case .none:
                self.backgroundEffectView?.alpha = 0
            }

        }
      }
     }

      enum BackgroundEffect {
       case blur
       case dim
       case none
      }
   ```
3. Create `SecondViewController` subclassing `OverlayViewController`:

   ```
    class SecondViewController: OverlayViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        addSlider()
    }

    func addSlider() {
        let sliderWidth:CGFloat = 100
        let centerOfScreen = self.view.frame.size.width / 2
        let rect = CGRect(x: centerOfScreen - sliderWidth/2, y: 80, width: sliderWidth, height: 10)
        let slider = UIView(frame: rect)
        slider.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(slider)
    }
   ```
4. Add `showOverlay()` function that will be triggered after `buttonPressed` and conform your presenting `UIViewController` (TestViewController) to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` :

   ```
    class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        showOverlay()
    }

    func showOverlay() {
        let secondVC =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
   }

    extension TestViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                                presenting: UIViewController?,
                                source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?
    {
        let presentedHeight: CGFloat = 1.0
        let controller = PresentationController(presentedViewController: presented,
                                                presenting: presenting,
                                                backgroundEffect: .dim,
                                                viewHeight: presentedHeight)

        if let vc = presented as? OverlayViewController {
            vc.delegate = controller
        }
        return controller
     }
    }
   ```
5. Now we should be able to present `SecondViewController` with `showOverlay()` function setting its `presentedHeight` to `1.0` and `.dim` background effect. We can dismiss `SecondViewController` similar to another modal presentations.

Comment: Will try on my project which has a lot of custom code. In a starter xcode app this worked!: Here's the code for anyone who wants it: https://github.com/MichaelGofron/TestPanGesture

Comment: @MichaelGofron Glad you like it  and thx for sharing!

Comment: Yup this seemed to work in my complex app as well. Now just need to find a way to make it work with our architecture. Thanks for the help!